# Ampersand and number sign (& and #)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql-server, json

Ampersands and number signs do not get stored in MS SQL whenever I insert data (and it will cut the next word after the ampersand and number sign). I’m using an `NVARCHAR` column on my MS SQL Server 2014.

For example if I type “AJ & J,” after I search it the output will be only “AJ.”

This is my JavaScript function:

```js
function GGPFUNCTION_AUTOSAVEHEADER() {
  var OBJECTS = object;
  var EVENTPARAMETER = 'INSERTUPDATE';
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../../../MODELS/86/MAINTENANCE/MODEL_86_SHIPPINGLINES.php?SHIPPINGLINENO=" + $("#SHIPPINGLINENO").val() +
      '&SHIPPINGLINENAME=' + $("#SHIPPINGLINENAME").val() +
      '&ADDRESS=' + $("#ADDRESS").val() +
      '&CONTACTPERSON=' + $("#CONTACTPERSON").val() +
      '&DESIGNATION=' + $("#DESIGNATION").val() +
      '&PHONENO=' + $("#PHONENO").val() +
      '&CONTACTNO=' + $("#CONTACTNO").val() +
      '&EMAILADDRESS=' + $("#EMAILADDRESS").val() +
      '&BLOCKED=' + $("#BLOCKED").val() +
      '&NOTEPADNO=' + notePadNo +
      '&USERNAME=' + username +
      '&OBJECTS=' + '<?php echo $_GET['
    objectno '];?>' +
    '&EVENTPARAMETER=' + EVENTPARAMETER,
    data: "",
    success: function(data) {
      $.each($.parseJSON(data), function() {


        if (this.ERROR.length != 0) {
          parent.test_error(this.ERROR);
          //$("#SHIPPINGLINENO").val('');
          $("#SHIPPINGLINENO").focus();

        } else {
          if (this.NEWMODE.length != 0) {
            $("#SHIPPINGLINENO").focus();
          }
          if (this.EXISTING.length != 0 && newMode == true) {
            newMode = false;
            searchMode = true;
            GGPFUNCTION_SEARCHHEADER_DOCUMENTNO(this.SHIPPINGLINENO);

          }
          if (this.EXISTING.length == 0 && this.SHIPPINGLINENO.length != 0) {
            $("#SHIPPINGLINENO").val(this.SHIPPINGLINENO);
          }
          newMode = false;
          searchMode = true;
        }

      });
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) is what you are after

Comment: where should i put it ? because i only want it on shipping line name and phone number.

Comment: you should use it where it is needed - have you read the link?

Comment: I suggest you saying `hash` instead of number sign

Comment: americans call it pound sign ... does it matter? :p

Comment: generically `'&KEY=' + encodeUriCompinent($('#blah').value)`

Comment: `i only want it on shipping line name` - you should use it on **all** values to future proof your code

Comment: actaully, you SHOULD do it on the keys as well (except they are hard coded, so it's safe not to)

Comment: &KEY is a function or string? Sorry im bit new to this :/

Comment: &KEY is a generic version of your parameters, like &PHONENO or &USERNAME in your code - I wasn't going to type all 12 of your parameters out, so I posted a generic version - I didn't realise your "experience level"

Comment: to spell it out in detail - https://jsfiddle.net/x0pjzc6g/ - however, it seems odd to use method `POST` and have no post data, you may as well use `GET` or change the query string to `data` - which wont require the encoding gymnastics

Comment: encodeURIcomponent worked when i insert beside the parameter. Thanks for your help though! :D  '&SHIPPINGLINENAME=' + encodeURIComponent($('#SHIPPINGLINENAME').val())+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use jQuery's [`jQuery.param()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) function to turn an object into a query string. This will do all the escaping for you.

```
var obj = {
  "SHIPPINGLINENO": $("#SHIPPINGLINENO").val(),
  "SHIPPINGLINENAME": $("#SHIPPINGLINENAME").val(),
  "ADDRESS": $("#ADDRESS").val(),
  "CONTACTPERSON": $("#CONTACTPERSON").val(),
  "DESIGNATION": $("#DESIGNATION").val(),
  "PHONENO": $("#PHONENO").val(),
  "CONTACTNO": $("#CONTACTNO").val(),
  "EMAILADDRESS": $("#EMAILADDRESS").val(),
  "BLOCKED": $("#BLOCKED").val(),
  "NOTEPADNO": notePadNo,
  "USERNAME": username,
  "OBJECTS": '<?php echo $_GET['objectno'];?>',
  "EVENTPARAMETER": EVENTPARAMETER
}
var querystring = $.param(obj);
```

Now you have a query string and can use it on the end of the URL:

```
url: "../../../MODELS/86/MAINTENANCE/MODEL_86_SHIPPINGLINES.php?" + querystring
```